Are there recent OR scientifical articles entirely written in Mandarin Chinese?
Can you cite or find them?
Related: What are the equivalent of western OR solvers developped by the People's Republic of China?

There are two journals listed on the site of the Operations Research Society of China, which publish papers in Chinese.
Operations Research and Management Science
http://www.jorms.net/CN/1007-3221/home.shtml
Operations Research Transactions
https://www.ort.shu.edu.cn/EN/article/showBrowseTopList.do
The articles can be found in English and Chinese. Be sure you are in the Chinese version of the page.
